# Stored procedure giving error while adding two more columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have an SP, which was working fine until I added two more columns. Now after adding two more columns it started giving error as

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

But I have already inserted that columns.

two newly added columns are

**Dept_received varchar(110),  doc_type varchar(110)**

Below is my SP.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Inward_Rec_Dept_doc]      
        @From_date Datetime,      
        @To_date Datetime      

        AS      
        BEGIN      
        CREATE TABLE #temp(      
        Dept_received varchar(110), doc_type varchar(110), date datetime, Total int,doc_From_To varchar(50),Inward int, First_Level_Transfer int,      
        Data_Entry_Transfer int,       
        Second_Level_Transfer int, Outward_Transfer int,      
        Closed int, Communication_Transfer int, Returned int     
    )      

      INSERT INTO #temp      
      (Dept_received, doc_type, date, Total,doc_From_To, Inward, First_Level_Transfer,      
       Data_Entry_Transfer,       
       Second_Level_Transfer, Outward_Transfer,      
       Closed, Communication_Transfer, Returned)      
      SELECT      
       doc_date, COUNT(*),      
     (select kk.doc_no FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr kk where mkey in (select min(mkey) FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr jj  
     where jj.doc_date =convert(datetime,aa.doc_date,103) )  )  
       + ' - '+  
     (select kk.doc_no FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr kk where mkey in (select max(mkey) FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr jj  
     where jj.doc_date =convert(datetime,aa.doc_date,103) )  )  
       ,SUM(      
       CASE      
        WHEN status_flag in ('6','23') THEN 1 ELSE 0      
       END)  
       ,SUM(      
       CASE      
          WHEN status_flag in ('4','26','24') THEN 1 ELSE 0      
       END)  
       ,SUM(      
       CASE      
          WHEN status_flag in ('15','20') THEN 1 ELSE 0      
       END),      
       SUM(      
       CASE      
          WHEN status_flag in ('17','21') THEN 1 ELSE 0      
       END),      
       SUM(      
       CASE      
          WHEN status_flag in ('18','27') THEN 1 ELSE 0      
       END),      
       SUM(      
       CASE      
          WHEN status_flag='5' THEN 1 ELSE 0      
       END),      
       SUM(      
       CASE      
          WHEN status_flag='16' THEN 1 ELSE 0      
       END),    
       SUM(      
       CASE      
          WHEN status_flag='14' THEN 1 ELSE 0      
       END)    
      FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr  aa    
      WHERE doc_date between @From_date and @To_date   
    --AND status_flag <> '6'      
      GROUP BY doc_date, Dept_received, doc_type    
END      

    Select * from #temp
```

I am using `sql-server-2005`

kindly help me what is the error

**updated query**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Inward_Rec_Dept_doc]      
            @From_date Datetime,      
            @To_date Datetime      

            AS      
            BEGIN      
            CREATE TABLE #temp( 
            Dept_received datetime, 
            doc_type varchar(110), date datetime, Total int,doc_From_To varchar(50), 
            Inward int, First_Level_Transfer int, 
            Data_Entry_Transfer int, 
            Second_Level_Transfer int, Outward_Transfer int, 
            Closed int, Communication_Transfer int, Returned int 
       )

          INSERT INTO #temp      
          (
                Dept_received, 
                doc_type, 
                date, 
                Total,
                doc_From_To, 
                Inward, 
                First_Level_Transfer,      
                Data_Entry_Transfer,       
                Second_Level_Transfer, 
                Outward_Transfer,      
                Closed, 
                Communication_Transfer, 
                Returned
               )      
          SELECT      
           doc_date, COUNT(*),      
         (select kk.doc_no FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr kk where mkey in (select min(mkey) FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr jj  
         where jj.doc_date =convert(datetime,aa.doc_date,103) )  )  
           + ' - '+  
         (select kk.doc_no FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr kk where mkey in (select max(mkey) FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr jj  
         where jj.doc_date =convert(datetime,aa.doc_date,103) )  )  
           ,SUM(      
           CASE      
            WHEN status_flag in ('6','23') THEN 1 ELSE 0      
           END)  
           ,SUM(      
           CASE      
              WHEN status_flag in ('4','26','24') THEN 1 ELSE 0      
           END)  
           ,SUM(      
           CASE      
              WHEN status_flag in ('15','20') THEN 1 ELSE 0      
           END),      
           SUM(      
           CASE      
              WHEN status_flag in ('17','21') THEN 1 ELSE 0      
           END),      
           SUM(      
           CASE      
              WHEN status_flag in ('18','27') THEN 1 ELSE 0      
           END),      
           SUM(      
           CASE      
              WHEN status_flag='5' THEN 1 ELSE 0      
           END),      
           SUM(      
           CASE      
              WHEN status_flag='16' THEN 1 ELSE 0      
           END),    
           SUM(      
           CASE      
              WHEN status_flag='14' THEN 1 ELSE 0      
           END),1,1  
          FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr  aa    
          WHERE doc_date between @From_date and @To_date   
        --AND status_flag <> '6'      
          GROUP BY doc_date, dept_received, doc_type 
  END      

  Select * from #temp
```

Comment: # of columns in table in which you're inserting and # of columns in table FROM which you're selecting to insert SHOULD be same. Add two more columns in your select clause.

Comment: you are trying to insert 11 values to 13 columns..

Comment: You have added `Dept_received, doc_type, ` into `INSERT`, but have not added them into `SELECT` before `doc_date, COUNT(*),`

Comment: @Y.B.: yes, I guess this might be the issue..let me try adding and check

Comment: @Sachu: i rechecked they are `13` in both select and insert

Comment: @Y.B.: now getting error as `Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.`

Comment: @Y.B.: updated the question with the query

Comment: @Y.B. It would be great if you could clearly specify what he is messed up by following my discussion with him?

Comment: @ShilpaSoni: can u join me on chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Inward_Rec_Dept_doc]      
    @From_date Datetime,      
    @To_date Datetime      

    AS      
    BEGIN      
    CREATE TABLE #temp(      
    Dept_received varchar(110),
     doc_type varchar(110), date datetime, Total int,doc_From_To varchar(50),
    Inward int, First_Level_Transfer int,      
    Data_Entry_Transfer int,       
    Second_Level_Transfer int, Outward_Transfer int,      
    Closed int, Communication_Transfer int, Returned int     
)      

  INSERT INTO #temp      
  (Dept_received, doc_type, date, Total,doc_From_To, Inward, First_Level_Transfer,      
   Data_Entry_Transfer,       
   Second_Level_Transfer, Outward_Transfer,      
   Closed, Communication_Transfer, Returned)      
  SELECT      
   doc_date, COUNT(*),      
 (select kk.doc_no FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr kk where mkey in (select min(mkey) FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr jj  
 where jj.doc_date =convert(datetime,aa.doc_date,103) )  )  
   + ' - '+  
 (select kk.doc_no FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr kk where mkey in (select max(mkey) FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr jj  
 where jj.doc_date =convert(datetime,aa.doc_date,103) )  )  
   ,SUM(      
   CASE      
    WHEN status_flag in ('6','23') THEN 1 ELSE 0      
   END)  
   ,SUM(      
   CASE      
      WHEN status_flag in ('4','26','24') THEN 1 ELSE 0      
   END)  
   ,SUM(      
   CASE      
      WHEN status_flag in ('15','20') THEN 1 ELSE 0      
   END),      
   SUM(      
   CASE      
      WHEN status_flag in ('17','21') THEN 1 ELSE 0      
   END),      
   SUM(      
   CASE      
      WHEN status_flag in ('18','27') THEN 1 ELSE 0      
   END),      
   SUM(      
   CASE      
      WHEN status_flag='5' THEN 1 ELSE 0      
   END),      
   SUM(      
   CASE      
      WHEN status_flag='16' THEN 1 ELSE 0      
   END),    
   SUM(      
   CASE      
      WHEN status_flag='14' THEN 1 ELSE 0      
   END),1,1  --Add your values in place of 1, your issue will be resolved    
  FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr  aa    
  WHERE doc_date between @From_date and @To_date   
--AND status_flag <> '6'      
  GROUP BY doc_date, Dept_received, doc_type    
END      

Select * from #temp
```

Comment: while executing the SP like this `exec Inward_Rec_Dept_doc '05-24-2016' , '05-26-2016'` i get error as `Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.`

Comment: try this: exec Inward_Rec_Dept_doc '2016-05-24' , '2016-05-26'

Comment: for side not **My dept_received and doc_type are integer values.**

Comment: @NK dude, apparently you are new to SQL. In "Dept_received" column you're inserting "doc_date". Do they both have same datatype? I doubt. In "doc_type" which is a varchar(110) type, you're inserting "count(*)" which would be an integer value.

Comment: so I shd add that Dept_received  column their too ? I am new to sql. kindly suggest some help

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about, but your issue definitely is in the datatype. Make sure inserting value's datatype matches with the table column's datatype.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113405/discussion-between-n-k-and-shilpa-soni).

Comment: shilpa, come on chat.. What I was wanted i have texted their

Answer (score 0):

You can save trouble aligning `INSERT`ed columns count and types with the temporary table structure by using `SELECT INTO`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Inward_Rec_Dept_doc]      
  @From_date Datetime,      
  @To_date Datetime      
AS      
BEGIN      
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp;

  SELECT
    doc_date As [date], dept_received, doc_type, COUNT(*) As Total
   ,(SELECT kk.doc_no FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr kk WHERE mkey in (SELECT min(mkey) FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr jj WHERE jj.doc_date = convert(datetime,aa.doc_date,103) ) )
    + ' - '+
    (SELECT kk.doc_no FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr kk WHERE mkey in (SELECT max(mkey) FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr jj WHERE jj.doc_date = convert(datetime,aa.doc_date,103) ) )
    As doc_From_To
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN status_flag in ( '6', '23')       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Inward
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN status_flag in ( '4', '26', '24') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As First_Level_Transfer
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN status_flag in ('15', '20')       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Data_Entry_Transfer
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN status_flag in ('17', '21')       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Second_Level_Transfer
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN status_flag in ('18', '27')       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Outward_Transfer
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN status_flag =    '5'              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Closed
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN status_flag =   '16'              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Communication_Transfer
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN status_flag =   '14'              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Returned
  INTO #temp
  FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr  aa
  WHERE doc_date between @From_date and @To_date
--AND status_flag <> '6'
  GROUP BY doc_date, dept_received, doc_type

END      
GO

Select * from #temp;
```

Comment: actually i resolved that error by placing `Dept_received,  doc_type` after `date` column in create part.. but where to write that in `select` kindly let me know

Comment: i added in select part, but getting error as `The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.`